# Vectorized "find and replace" in data frame in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I am attempting do make a vectorized "find and replace" of multiple strings in a data frame. In my mock data frame below, I want to replace "human" with "dog", and "cat" with "moose"
.

Mock input:

```
df<-data.frame(organism=c("human","cat","bird","virus","bat","pangolian"),size=c(6,4,2,1,3,5))
df
   organism size
1     human    6
2       cat    4
3      bird    2
4     virus    1
5       bat    3
6 pangolian    5
```

expected output:

```
df1
   organism size
1       dog    6
2     moose    4
3      bird    2
4     virus    1
5       bat    3
6 pangolian    5
```

In reality, I have a large data frame and many replacements, so I would want to have my replacement strings in a vector like this:

```
replacement<-c("dog","moose")
```

I know this is supposed to be simply to solve, but as a newbie I simply can't get my head around it. So, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_replace` from `stringr` :

```
pattern <- c('human', 'cat')
replacement <- c('dog', 'moose')
df$organism <- stringr::str_replace(df$organism, pattern, replacement)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ronak. I was trying to do exactly this with the sub() function, but failed as that function is not vectorised like the str_replace() function.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do find and replace. The following approach uses a named vector only, similar to a python dictionary:

```
organism_map <- levels(df$organism)
names(organism_map) <- organism_map
organism_map["human"] <- "dog"
organism_map["cat"] <- "moose"
```

The `organism_map` contains the mapping:

```
  human         cat        bird       virus         bat   pangolian 
  "dog"     "moose"      "bird"     "virus"       "bat" "pangolian"
```

Then you just look up the `organism_map` vector values in the order of `df$organism` names, the result is saved back to `df$organism` column:

```
df$organism <- organism_map[df$organism]
```

Result:

```
   organism size
1       dog    6
2     moose    4
3      bird    2
4     virus    1
5       bat    3
6 pangolian    5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Emer. I will try to get my head around this solution cause it sure works : )